# Converting author_id to author_username with R

Tags: r, rtweet

There is an "sourcetweet_author_id" column in my dataset (of around 30000 tweets) which includes the twitter id of quoted and retweeted users. I want to convert the twitter id to twitter user name.

I managed to gather user names of the "sourcetweet_author_id" with rtweet package's lookup_users function.

```
data.with.usernames <- lookup_users(as_userid(mydata$sourcetweet_author_id))
```

sample output:

sample data:

| "user_id" | "status_id" | "created_at" | "screen_name" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "99564663" | "1521494990890876929" | 2022-05-03 14:20:48 | "LeventUzumcu" |
| "4274638635" | "1521110034515701760" | 2022-05-02 12:51:07 | "SalihaSnmezate1" |
| "1266093027254325250" | "1300887103874707457" | 2020-09-01 20:03:49 | "arjin3426" |
| "1494034783" | "1521523729599107073" | 2022-05-03 16:15:00 | "DikenComTr" |

But this function only returned the list of unique users. It is quite normal because my dataset includes many retweets from the same tweet.

Now, I need a function to match each sourcetweet_author_id with its user name and use that function to convert all the  ids in "user_id" column to usernames in a new column.

sample data table of my original dataset:

| "sourcetweet_author_id" | "created_at" | "retweet_count" | "like_count" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "99564663" | "2020-07-23T14:00:39.000Z" | 8031 | 0 |
| "99564663" | "2020-07-23T14:00:35.000Z" | 7153 | 0 |
| "1266093027254325250" | "2020-07-23T14:00:29.000Z" | 7153 | 0 |
| "1266093027254325250" | "2020-07-23T14:00:29.000Z" | 6596 | 0 |

Comment: you should include the code you ran to allow others to reproduce your problem

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You can probably use `lookup_users` to create a `data.frame` with both the `author_id` and the `user_id` then [join](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html) it with your original based by `user_id = sourcetweet_author_id`.

Comment: Sound like a simple merge of two datasets or possibly a merge of one with itself. As already commented….. need a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should add the `screen_name` column to `original_dataset`:

```
library(dplyr)
original_dataset %>%
  left_join(
    select(data.with.usernames, sourcetweet_author_id = user_id, screen_name)
  )
```